# Apexcharts change color on bar per categories

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

I copied the demo for the apexcharts javascript Column Charts > Column with Group Label and I want to change the colors grouped by categories. How to do this? Here's from the sample demo

```
var options = {
      series: [{
      name: "sales",
      data: [{
        x: '2019/01/01',
        y: 400
      }, {
        x: '2019/04/01',
        y: 430
      }, {
        x: '2019/07/01',
        y: 448
      }, {
        x: '2019/10/01',
        y: 470
      }, {
        x: '2020/01/01',
        y: 540
      }, {
        x: '2020/04/01',
        y: 580
      }, {
        x: '2020/07/01',
        y: 690
      }, {
        x: '2020/10/01',
        y: 690
      }]
    }],
      chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      height: 380
    },
    xaxis: {
      type: 'category',
      labels: {
        formatter: function(val) {
          return "Q" + dayjs(val).quarter()
        }
      },
      group: {
        style: {
          fontSize: '10px',
          fontWeight: 700
        },
        groups: [
          { title: '2019', cols: 4 },
          { title: '2020', cols: 4 }
        ]
      }
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Grouped Labels on the X-axis',
    },
    tooltip: {
      x: {
        formatter: function(val) {
          return "Q" + dayjs(val).quarter() + " " + dayjs(val).format("YYYY")
        }  
      }
    },
    };

    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
    chart.render();
```

I tried below but the first color applied to all bar columns.

```
colors: ['#FF0000', '#00FFFF']
```

Other try is but still the same. I cant get to work to update bar columns per category:

```
fill: {
        colors: [function({ value, seriesIndex, w }) {
            
            index = Math.floor(seriesIndex / $group_count);

            return '#7E36AF';
            
        }]
    },
```

Comment: ApexCharts uses the "colors" array to set the color for each series, not for individual data points within a series. Since your chart is set up with only one series "sales", setting the colors array will apply the same color to all bars in that series.

If you want each group of bars (grouped by year in your case) to have different colors, you will need to structure your data into multiple series, each representing a group.

Answer (score 0):

Axis groups can only be used to format that axis' labels; the groups
cannot be used to target properties of the bars themselves.

If colors are the only thing you want to change, the simplest way is to
assign individual colors for each data point, see the
[docs on column charts](https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/column-chart/) at "Changing the color of a particular data-point":

```js
   data: [{
      x: '2019/01/01',
      y: 400,
      fillColor: '#f00'
   }, {
      x: '2019/04/01',
      y: 430,
      fillColor: '#f00'
   }, {
      x: '2019/07/01',
      y: 448,
      fillColor: '#f00'
   }, {
      x: '2019/10/01',
      y: 470,
      fillColor: '#f00'
   }, {
      x: '2020/01/01',
      y: 540,
      fillColor: '#0fa'
   }, {
      x: '2020/04/01',
      y: 580,
      fillColor: '#0fa'
   }, {
      x: '2020/07/01',
      y: 690,
      fillColor: '#0fa'
   }, {
      x: '2020/10/01',
      y: 690,
      fillColor: '#0fa'
   }]
```

Of course, that can be performed automatically, by mapping a function to the
data array, e.g.,

```js
   data: [{
      x: '2019/01/01',
      y: 400
   }, {
      x: '2019/04/01',
      y: 430
   }, {
      x: '2019/07/01',
      y: 448
   }, {
      x: '2019/10/01',
      y: 470
   }, {
      x: '2020/01/01',
      y: 540
   }, {
      x: '2020/04/01',
      y: 580
   }, {
      x: '2020/07/01',
      y: 690
   }, {
      x: '2020/10/01',
      y: 690
   }].map(
      ({x, y}) => ({x, y, fillColor: x.match(/^2019/) ? '#f00' : '#0af'})
   )
```

Full snippet:

```js
dayjs.extend(dayjs_plugin_quarterOfYear)
var options = {
   series: [{
      name: "sales",
      data: [{
         x: '2019/01/01',
         y: 400
      }, {
         x: '2019/04/01',
         y: 430
      }, {
         x: '2019/07/01',
         y: 448
      }, {
         x: '2019/10/01',
         y: 470
      }, {
         x: '2020/01/01',
         y: 540
      }, {
         x: '2020/04/01',
         y: 580
      }, {
         x: '2020/07/01',
         y: 690
      }, {
         x: '2020/10/01',
         y: 690
      }].map(({x, y})=> ({x, y, fillColor: x.match(/^2019/) ? '#f00' : '#0af'}))
   }],
   chart: {
      type: 'bar',
      height: 380
   },
   xaxis: {
      type: 'category',
      labels: {
         formatter: function(val) {
            return "Q" + dayjs(val).quarter()
         }
      },
      group: {
         style: {
            fontSize: '10px',
            fontWeight: 700
         },
         groups: [
            { title: '2019', cols: 4 },
            { title: '2020', cols: 4 }
         ]
      }
   },
   title: {
      text: 'Grouped Labels on the X-axis',
   },
   tooltip: {
      x: {
         formatter: function(val) {
            return "Q" + dayjs(val).quarter() + " " + dayjs(val).format("YYYY")
         }
      }
   }
};

const chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/apexcharts/3.37.1/apexcharts.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-hl0UXLK2ElpaU9SHbuVNsvFv2BaYszlhxB2EntUy5FTGdfg9wFJrJG2JDcT4iyKmWeuDLmK+Nr2hLoq2sKk6MQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.10/dayjs.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-FwNWaxyfy2XlEINoSnZh1JQ5TRRtGow0D6XcmAWmYCRgvqOUTnzCxPc9uF35u5ZEpirk1uhlPVA19tflhvnW1g=="
      crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.10/plugin/quarterOfYear.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-pWtHtIgIdv64mVaEbh1ACEvfsrMvdSuJ7xGLzm3s1LiSPyA2pGit3cjTBHvFQCkXoX2r9drLdcfAP7C8eGbBTQ=="
      crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: this works well. I did not know it was this simple. thanks very much